# Stop Angular Material Menu from showing URL link when not hovering on a menu item

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to use `<a>` as menu items so that I get the display of the URL link at the bottom left corner in the browser when the mouse pointer is hovering above the menu item (if this behaviour is browser dependent then at least Chrome does this).

However, it seems once the menu is shown, the URL link of the first menu item is already showing at the bottom left corner, even when not mouse hovering it.

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pbvns

How do you stop the URL links from showing unless you mouse hovering on the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by changing focus to menu trigger whenever menu opens

**component.html**

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" 
(menuOpened)="menuTrigger.focus()" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <a mat-menu-item href="link 1">Item 1</a>
  <a mat-menu-item href="link 2">Item 2</a>
</mat-menu>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pbvns-kijuu3?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.html)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. But that breaks the keyboard focus function if the menu is opened by [Enter] or [Space]...

Comment: yes you need press tab to move focus once open the menu